# Why can´t I import data to my schema in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with two schemas hosted on AWS. I'm trying to import data from another database to it using the import data method. One of the schemas imports the data without problems, but the other one throws this error:

```
ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 49: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

What I don´t get is why one schema works and the other doesn't. What kind of permissions might be different?

Comment: The SUPER privilege, maybe? What are you trying to do on line 49 exactly?